# Angular filter hangs on large data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have created an application where I have about 1000 entries and my ng repeat look like this

```
item in items| filter:searchQuery
```

here searchQuery is a model attached to an input field, the problem is when a user types something in this field then the browser hangs due to huge amount of items on client side resulting in slow filtering, is there anyway to make it more user friendly?

Comment: 1000 entries shouldn't ideally be a problem. Can you post the code for your filter?

Comment: @Tarun that is all that I have in my code, angular fires the keyup(like) function which is filtering on each word a user types and then for a second the screen freezes

Comment: try by changing searchQuery to just 'search'. I am not sure if there is an inbuilt filter by the name of 'searchQuery'

Comment: @Tarun searchQuery is just a model name it can be anything xyz and angular's default filter is watching this variable before putting the items

Comment: Would it be acceptable, if you provide a button which then runs a filter on items using the 'searchQuery' model instead of firing the filter whenever the user types in the input element.

Comment: @Tarun Yes it will, I thought about that too but the problem is in that case I need to show a loader and I am not sure if angular provides a callback after filtering is completed so I will not be able to hide loader afterwards

Comment: @Tarun I need to show loader because if I wont then it will again hang for a second or two

Comment: i avoided this by doing http request every time someone would filter something.If it's onkeypress you can make a request every 0.5-1sec(with timeout) to avoid making requests every keypress. I had more data than you so it was not userfriendly to make them wait with a frozen screen. Since the server can request a new query pretty fast that's how i solved it.

Comment: @Marcio That is my only problem, I don't have the access to the server code maybe I will add a timeout and check